# Formatting numbers with percentage points (p.p.)

Tags: siunitx

I am using the `siunitx` package for formatting numbers along with certain units. The package is included with the following code:

```
\usepackage[
    detect-weight,
    exponent-product=\cdot,
    locale = DE,
    group-separator=.,
]{siunitx}
```

However, I am struggling to use the `p.p.` unit for designating percentage points. I don't seem to find any predefined unit like `\percent`, so I have tried this:

```
\SI{1}{p.p.}
```

But the commas seem to be left out and the result looks like this:

[image]

If I improvise and use `\num{1}~p.p.`, then the result looks OK, but the space between the number and the unit is somewhat bigger. First line: `\SI{1}{p.p.}`, second line `\num{1}~p.p.`

[image]

**Question**: any ideas on how to use `p.p.` along with the `\SI` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a new unit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  detect-weight,
  exponent-product=\cdot,
  locale = DE,
  group-separator=.,
]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pp}{\textup{p.p.}}

\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\pp} -- $\SI{1}{\pp}$ -- \textbf{\SI{1}{\pp}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very simple, but effective.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in the manual, `.` is taken in units as a unit separator (as units are *not* abbreviations there is usually no issue with this). If you want to prevent this happening, the easiest way is to add a set of braces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{p{.}p{.}}
\end{document}
```